# Create a /16 (255.255.0.0) local network

Tags: networking, local-area-network

My bare knuckles networking understanding led me to believe that if I set an IP address of, for example, 10.0.2.25 with netmask 255.255.0.0 on a machine, it should see all hosts in the subnet 10.0.1.0/24 (and many others on the whole 10.0.0.0/16 subnet)

I just tried it, but the machine with 10.0.2.25/16 didn't see at all 10.0.1.0/24 addresses.

Two questions:

1. How to set up such a network simply?
2. What's the mistake in my understanding?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work)

Comment: @TomO'Connor I'm not sure this practical question is answered *directly* in the canonical answer about IPv4 subnets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I just tried it, but the machine with 10.0.2.25/16 didn't see at all 10.0.1.0/24 addresses

10.0.2.25/16 can send packets to 10.0.1.0/24, but when 10.0.1.0/24 tries to respond it thinks the opther host is outside it's network hence will try to send the packets back through a router (or fail).

Answer (score 4):

> How to set up such a network simply?

Just as you did, you got it right in principal, there must just be an issue with the implementation - certainly there's nothing wrong with the idea of doing what you did.

> What's the mistake in my understanding?

Nothing, you just need to ensure that this use of a /16 is implemented everywhere appropriate, on every machine in that range, in every router etc.

Use of non-/24 netmasks is extremely common these days and works great, but you do need to ensure they're properly, and thoroughly, implemented.

Otherwise good work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, if the other machine is a /24, it can only see machines in that scope. The subnet masks need to match if they are going to be visible to one another.